# Ajax call when clicking on a button in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, haml

I basically want to create an alert when clicking on a button, withour reloading the entire page.

Into my view :

```
:javascript
  function ajax_test1(field)
  {
      var xmlhttp;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      xmlhttp.open("GET", "test_ajax.xml?code=" + field.value, false);
      xmlhttp.send();
      xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
      alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("message")[0].childNodes[0]);
  }
```

and

```
= button_to 'test ajax', :remote => true, :onclick => "ajax_test1(this);"
```

Into my controller

```
  def test_ajax
    @test = {message:'Hello there!'}
    render :xml => @test
  end
```

When I click on the button, the page is reloading with the following URL:

```
http://localhost:4242/test?onclick=ajax_test1%28this%29%3B&remote=true
```

How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this :

```
= button_to 'test ajax', :remote => true, :onclick => "ajax_test1(this);"
```

into this:

```
 = button_to_function 'test ajax', 'ajax_test1(this)'
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

The onclick event needs to return `false` in order to halt the default behaviour – the actual click – from taking place.

If you were using jQuery, the `.preventDefault()` method is a nicer way of preventing the default event behaviour – but with your hand rolled javascript you'll have to be a bit messier:

```
= button_to 'test ajax', :remote => true, :onclick => "ajax_test1(this); return false;"
```

Comment: I added the `return false;` but got the same result