# remote true on button_to not makes ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, button-to

I am doing a small rails app.

I am trying to make an ajax call.
Despite I use `remote: true` the button_to is making a non ajax request. It redirects me to this url `http://localhost:3000/lines?product_id=1`

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= link_to product.name, controller: "store", action: "show", id: product %><br>
  <%= button_to "Add to Cart", {controller: "lines", action: "create", product_id: product.id}, method: "POST", remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

[github repo](https://github.com/gerard-morera/colossus_shop/blob/26-add-product-to-cart/app/views/store/index.html.erb)

Any idea?

Thanks!

---EDIT---
this was my application.js

```
= require jquery
= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: You can get rid of `method` - post is a default.

Comment: Worth adding your application.js as that appears to be the cause of the problem.

Comment: check this seems duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710040/ajax-call-when-clicking-on-a-button-in-rails

Comment: @Arv - Some issue, different reason. :) Shadwell answer is correct. :)

Answer (score 2):

Issues like this are usually because you aren't loading jquery correctly. The `button_to ... remote: true` becomes an ajax call because the `remote: true` triggers javascript that changes the behaviour of the button.

In your `application.js` you are requiring javascript with:

```
= require jquery
= require jquery_ujs
```

This should be:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

With jquery loaded correctly you should get the button behaving as expected.

Comment: Thanks @Shadwell! You are right. Why is it wrong to require jquery?

Comment: It's not wrong to require it it's the way it was being required. The lines really do need that "commented out" format as that is what the asset pipeline expects. (I don't think you need the `//= require jquery` as `jquery_ujs` includes it.